# OpenCV and mediapipe pushup counter project in PYTHON

Tags: python, opencv, project, mediapipe

I am trying this OpenCV project of pushup counter but when I try to run this code the camera window is not opening please help me to solve this.
The camera light gets turned ON but the window of Camera is not opening.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as md

md_drawing=md.solutions.drawing_utils
md_drawing_styles=md.solutions.drawing_styles
md_pose=md.solutions.pose

count = 0

position=None

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

with md_pose.Pose(
    min_detection_confidence=0.7,
    min_tracking_confidence=0.7) as pose:
    while cap.isOpened():
        success,image=cap.read()
        if not success:
            print("empty camera")
            break

            image=cv2.cvtColor(cv2.flip(image,1),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            result=pose.process(image)
            
            imlist=[]

            if result.pose_landmarks:
                md_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                    image,result.pose_landmarks,md_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
                for id,im in enumerate(result.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                    h,w,_=image.shape
                    X,Y=int(im.x*w),int(im.y*h)
                    imlist.append([id,X,Y])
            #print(imlist)


            if Len(imlist) != 0:
                if((imlist[12][2]-imlisit[14][2]) >= 15 and (imlist[11][2]-imlist[13][2])>=15):
                    position="down"
                if((imlist[12][2]-imlisit[14][2]) <= 5 and (imlist[11][2]-imlist[13][2])<=5) and position == "down":
                    position="up"
                    count+=1
                    print(count)

            cv2.imshow("Push-up counter",cv2.flip(image,1))
            key=cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key==ord('q'):
                break

cap.release()
```

Comment: Please check the indentation after the first `break` in line 21. The code after this line will never be executed!

Comment: love you brother for helping.........